# Outlook add-in - blank body after replacing scrolling text

Tags: ms-office, office365, outlook-addin

I'm working on an Office365 add-in for Outlook 2016 that allows users to change the body of an email using buttons in a task pane.

HTML in Task Pane:

```
 <p><button onclick="createLongBody()">Set Long Body</button></p>
 <p><button onclick="createShortBody()">Set Short Body</button></p>
 <div id="status"></div>
```

In Javascript:

```
function createLongBody() {

    var longText = "<html><body>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/>Hello<br/></body></html>";
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(longText, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, function () {
        $("#status").html("Long email complete!");
    });
};

function createShortBody() {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync("<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>", { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, function () {
        $("#status").html("Short email complete!");
    });
```

To replicate:

1. Click "Create Long Body" button
2. Scroll to bottom, place cursor at end of email
3. Click "Create Short Body" button

Result:

The status text changes to "Short email complete", but the new short email does not appear - the body is simply blank.

I'm not sure if this is an Office add-in API bug, but wanted to present it to the community to see if anyone had any ideas?
Can anyone else replicate? Thanks!

*Edited with HTML/JS to replicate*

Answer (score 1):

Did you call the subsequent call in the callback of the first call of changing the body context? If not it may not work expected since the **setAsync** is asynchronous function.

I am trying to reproduce this issue, however failed. The test function below works well for me:

```
  function setBody() {
    var theHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello</h1><h2> Jack,</h2><h3>Rose</h3> <h4>..</h4><h1>Hello</h1><h2> Jack,</h2><h3>Rose</h3> <h4>..</h4><h1>Hello</h1><h2> Jack,</h2><h3>Rose</h3> <h4>..</h4><h1>Hello</h1><h2> Jack,</h2><h3>Rose</h3> <h4>..</h4><h1>Hello</h1><h2> Jack,</h2><h3>Rose</h3> <h4>..</h4></body></html>";
    Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(theHtml, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, function (asyncResult) {
       var newHtml= theHtml.replace(/Rose/g, "rose");
       Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(newHtml, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html });
    });
}
```

If you still have the issue would you mind sharing a complete code to help us to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Thanks @FeiXue! I've edited the question with more code to reflect the situation better. I'm not running the second edit programmatically; The user has to click another button to change the body again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it worked for me. I copy pasted your functions and ran createLongBody() then createShortBody() and the body of the e-mail was replaced.

What version of Outlook Are you on?

[image]

Comment: In Outlook 2016. Was your cursor at the bottom of the long email when you clicked the short email button? It only happens when you scroll to the bottom and click, so your cursor is at the end of the long email. (See step #2). Thanks for trying to replicate!

Comment: Yeah, I clicked so the insertion pointer was at the end of the last Hello (after running the createLongBody()) function.

Do you have the *specific* version number of Outlook 2016. It can be obtained by going to File-> Office Account -> About Outlook

Comment: Version 16.0.4266.1003 (32-bit)